# MPI: Why does mpiexec stall when running an MPI program on remote hosts?

Tags: mpi, mpiexec

I am testing the mpiexec function, but when the processes are finished on the first host, the next host does not finish the process,  remain the process eternally paused. The code I am using is the following:

mpiexec -hosts 2 158.42.179.5 1 158.42.179.6 1 test_mpi

```
Hello world: rank            0  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5

 Hello world: rank            1  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5

 Hello world: rank            2  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5

 Hello world: rank            3  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5

 Hello world: rank            4  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5

 Hello world: rank            5  of           12  running on
 158.42.179.5
```

In the second host you can see how the processes are started, but always occupying the same amount of memory:

[image: Processes created]

Has anyone experienced similar behavior? The computers are visible to each other, and respond to ping. I am doing the test in the CMD of fds software.

In addition, in the second host the process is consuming all the resources:

[image]

Comment: I am surprised there is an `mpiexec.exe` running on the second host. are you sure these are not unrelated processes from a previous session?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that before execution there is no active process on the second host. This second host is the localhost from which I launch the process, can this be the problem?